# Print a string in reverse order

Tags: java, reverse

I want to print an input in reverse order.

```
public class ReverseDictionary {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter string: ");
        String a = in.nextLine();

        for (int i=a.length()-1; i<=0; i--){
            System.out.print(a.charAt(i));
        }   
    }
}
```

So if the input is "hello", it should print out "olleh" but in my situation it doesn't print anything at all.

Comment: condition in for loop should be i>=0

Comment: Dude... if you can't get this down you really are gonna need to crack open a book...

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `new StringBuilder(varName).reverse().toString()` to get the reversed string and then print it directly.

Answer (score 2):

Your loop condition is wrong, use

```
for (int i = a.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
```

instead.

Notice the `>=` instead of the `<=`.

If the length is 5, the condition `5 <= 0` is never satisfied.

Comment: Such small mistake makes the difference! thanks

Comment: You could use debuger for figuring it out.

Answer (score 2):

Condition should be reversed from `<=` to `>=`

```
for (int i=a.length()-1; i>=0; i--){
    System.out.print(a.charAt(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Push each String character onto a `Stack` and then just pop the `Stack` until it is empty.